# ShowCaret and SetCaretPos failing with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c++, winapi

What could cause `ShowCaret` and `SetCaretPos` to fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`?

I'm creating the caret in `WM_CREATE` and showing the caret in `WM_COMMAND`.
I checked and `CreateCaret` is executing successfully.

They should be running in the same thread.

I use `SetScrollInfo` and `InvalidateRect` before calling `ShowCaret` to update the content of my window. But I don't think these would cause `ShowCaret` to fail..

**RELEVANT CODE:**

```
#define CHAR_WIDTH  7
#define CHAR_HEIGHT 12

case WM_CREATE:
    CreateCaret(hWnd, NULL, CHAR_WIDTH, 2);
    UpdateScrollbar(hWnd); // calls SetScrollInfo. initially nMin and nMax are both 0
    return 0;

case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDM_OPENFILE:
        if (DoOpenFile(hWnd))
        {
            InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
            UpdateScrollbar(hWnd);

            if (SetCaretPos(CHAR_WIDTH * 12, CHAR_HEIGHT - 1) == 0)
            {
                char ss[33];
                sprintf_s(ss, "DEBUG 2: %d\n", GetLastError());
                OutputDebugString(ss);
            }

            if (ShowCaret(hWnd) == 0)
            {
                char ss[33];
                sprintf_s(ss, "DEBUG 3: %d\n", GetLastError());
                OutputDebugString(ss);
            }
        }
        break;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Is the window your window? Created by the process that calls `ShowCaret` and `SetCaretPos`? Possible failure mode is password protected screensaver. Which version of the OS?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yup my window. Windows 7 x64

Comment: That code looks good to me. I'm out of ideas now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are not doing this correctly.  There is only one caret per message queue (in other words, per thread).  You cannot create a caret when another window already has one, an edit box being the most likely case.  You *must* not create the caret or show it until your window receives the focus, WM_SETFOCUS message.  And you *must* destroy it when the window loses focus, WM_KILLFOCUS message.

The way you use GetLastError() is also dangerous, albeit that you probably get away with it right now.  The order in which arguments get evaluated in C or C++ is not deterministic.  You run the risk of one of the argument expressions altering the error code.  Always obtain the error code before calling anything else, store it in a local variable.

And *never* skip error checking, at the very minimum you must assert() the return value.  The CreateCaret() call is likely to be failing right now since a window that just got created will never have the focus.